# What is the right way to configure Apache to serve a project over a local network

Tags: apache, ip, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I have my project running in an apache virtual host.
the name of the conf file is `btapp.local.conf`
this is the content of the file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName btapp.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/btapp/app/webroot


<Directory /var/www/btapp/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

My local network IP is `addr:192.168.3.218`
But when i am trying to access the project from the network by `192.168.3.218/btapp.local` I am getting the error `The requested URL /btapp.local was not found on this server.`
As of now, I have edited my `000-default.conf` and put the content of `btapp.local.conf` (basically i have pointed default host to the path of the project)
I want to know the follwing things
1.Is this the right way to serve a project over the network? 
2.Are there other ways that I can use to serve the project through the network without modifying the `000-default.conf` file?

EDIT
this is my `/etc/hosts` file content

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 bonnie
127.0.1.1 btapp.local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way can be to set up a virtual host and run it in a different port.
To set up a port mention the port in the `ports.conf` file in the `etc/apache2` path

this is the `ports.conf` file that i am using

```
Listen 80
Listen 81

<IfModule ssl_module>
   Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

In this case, I have set `81` as a new port
configure a virtual host to  run on this port
this is my `000-default.conf` in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` path

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/btapp/app/webroot
    <Directory /var/www/btapp/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

1. So, to answer my 1st question, yes there is a way to serve the project over the network without overwriting the default configuration of `local` port `80` 
2.default.conf file doesnot need to be modified if the virtual host is created into a seperate conf.